# get Value of Input tag using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<ul id="temp-list">
<li id="CommCheck" > Comm Check </li>
<input id="CommCheck-data" type="hidden" value="text1" />
....
</ul>


var vdata = $(ui.draggable).attr("id")+'-data'; /this gives me the CommCheck-data
alert(vdata); 
var text-data = $(vdata).val(); // should give me the value of Input id: "CommCheck-data"
alert(text-data); // but this states undefined ???
```

how do i get the input value ?
am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: That isn't your actual HTML markup is it? An `<input>` can't be a direct child of a `<ul>` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a "#" in front to tell jQuery it's an ID, not a tag name:

```
$("#" + vdata).val();
```

Also javascript variables cannot contain dashes in them. Try `var textData`.